# Blackberry Java TableView: calculateVerticalScrollAmount Exception?

Tags: java, blackberry, user-interface

I'm getting a "TableView(ScrollView).calculateVerticalScrollAmount(XYRect)" exception when trying to create a table using the following code.  I've tried simplifying the fields, but nothing seems to help, any thoughts?  The code is similar to that in the Tables Demo supplied with the BB 6 SDK.

It looks like a layout issue, but I can't seem to pin down the error.

```
    // Create and apply style
    RegionStyles style = new RegionStyles(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(1, 1, 1, 1), Border.STYLE_SOLID), null, null,
    null, RegionStyles.ALIGN_LEFT, RegionStyles.ALIGN_TOP);

    // Create the view and controller
    TableView tableView = new TableView(_tableModel);
    TableController tableController = new TableController(_tableModel, tableView);

    // Set the controller focus policy to highlight rows
    tableController.setFocusPolicy(TableController.ROW_FOCUS);

    // Set the behaviour of the controller when a table item is clicked
    tableController.setCommand(new CommandHandler()
    {
        /**
         * @see CommandHandler#execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata, Object)
         */
        public void execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata metadata, Object context)
        {
            Dialog.alert("Command Executed");
        }

    }, null, null);

    tableView.setController(tableController);

    // Create a DataTemplate that suppresses the third column
    DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(tableView, 2, 3)
    {
        /**
         * @see DataTemplate#getDataFields(int)
         */
        public Field[] getDataFields(int modelRowIndex)
        {
            Object[] data = (Object[]) ((TableModel) getView().getModel()).getRow(modelRowIndex);

            Field[] fields = new Field[4];
            fields[0] = new BitmapField((Bitmap) data[0]);
            fields[1] = new LabelField(data[1], Field.FOCUSABLE);
            fields[2] = new LabelField(data[2], Field.FOCUSABLE);
            fields[3] = new LabelField(data[3], Field.FOCUSABLE);

            return fields;
        }
    };

    // Set up regions
    dataTemplate.createRegion(new XYRect(0, 0, 1, 2), style);
    dataTemplate.createRegion(new XYRect(1, 0, 2, 1), style);
    dataTemplate.createRegion(new XYRect(1, 1, 1, 1), style);
    dataTemplate.createRegion(new XYRect(2, 1, 1, 1), style);

    // Specify the size of each column by percentage, and the height of a row        
    dataTemplate.setColumnProperties(0, new TemplateColumnProperties(15, TemplateColumnProperties.PERCENTAGE_WIDTH));
    dataTemplate.setColumnProperties(1, new TemplateColumnProperties(15, TemplateColumnProperties.PERCENTAGE_WIDTH));
    dataTemplate.setColumnProperties(2, new TemplateColumnProperties(70, TemplateColumnProperties.PERCENTAGE_WIDTH));
    dataTemplate.setRowProperties(0, new TemplateRowProperties(ROW_HEIGHT));
    dataTemplate.setRowProperties(1, new TemplateRowProperties(ROW_HEIGHT));

    // Apply the template to the view
    tableView.setDataTemplate(dataTemplate);
    dataTemplate.useFixedHeight(true);

    add(tableView);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you are still struggling with this - may be benefits for others

in the statement

```
DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(tableView, 2, 3)
```

you have initialized the DataTemplate with 2 rows and 3 columns (assuming you want to suppress 4th column). But inside the function `getDataFields` you are returning 4 fields.

This is causing the crash (the internal code is not monkey proof).
Drop the 4th field from array and it should work.